# Japanese equivalent for "Beta" as in software prototype or early release?

Tags: word-requests

What are the most common terms used by the software industry in Japan to list software as "beta" as in an early release. And how would they translate literally to American English?

Beta software defined as not officially released but available to a select number of individuals for testing.
https://techterms.com/definition/beta_software

While there might be some phrases, I am looking for the short version which would be easily recognizable.

Comment: 30 seconds and a dictionary gives me ベータ版 https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%83%99%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E7%89%88

Comment: @Mindful your dictionary might be better than mine? i got `ベータ`

Comment: eow.alc.co.jp is pretty good; I like it. ベータ may or may not get your point across, but it's used in a couple different things, whereas ベータ版 explicitly means "beta version", despite still being relatively sort. 版 is similarly used for 体験版, which means "trial version".

Comment: I even saw this `バータ版　（ばん）- beta version (of software)` as a translation listed somewhere but the reason i posted here was so discuss what the Japanese text actually means.

Comment: ^ You sure it was **バ**ータ[版]{ばん}, not **ベ**ータ版? バータ版って何だろう・・

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to comment but did not have enough reps. As a Japanese, I think ベータ版 is the most common term that cannot be mistaken for anything else.

Comment: Regardless of the number of reps, you should not use the comment section to post an answer ;)

Comment: β版 is also used (also noted in the [Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%99%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E7%89%88)). I saw this in the wild when Slack was rolling out their Japanese translation for the Windows desktop app.